# RESTful API, patch, mongoose update command doesn't update instead just clears fields

Tags: mongodb, rest, mongoose

`Patch` method with mongoose `update` doesn't work instead  just clears field which I try to update. I have tried `update`, `updateOne`, `updateMany` and I have tried to do this through the flag `$set` the result is the same - clear field which I have tried to update. (Get, delete work perfectly, there is a problem only with put and patch)

The code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const _ = require("lodash")

app.use(express.static(__dirname))

const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const parser = require("body-parser")

app.use(parser.urlencoded({extended:true}))

const ejs = require("ejs");
app.set("view engine", "ejs")



mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/wikiDB", {useNewUrlParser:true})
 
const articlesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title:String,
    content:String
})

const articlesCollection = mongoose.model("article", articlesSchema)

///targeting all articles 

app.route("/articles").get(function(req,res){
    articlesCollection.find({}, (err, foundArticle) => {
      if(!err) {
          res.send(foundArticle);
      } else {
          console.log(err);
    }
    })
})
.post(function(req,res) {

    const newArticle = new articlesCollection({
        title:req.body.title,
        content:req.body.content    
    });

    newArticle.save(function(err){
        if(!err) {
            res.send("success");
        } else {res.send(err)}
    })

})
.delete(function(req,res){
    articlesCollection.deleteMany({}, function(err){
        err ? res.send(err) : res.send("successfully deleted")
    })
});

///target a specific article
 
app.route("/articles/:parameter")

.get(function(req,res){

    const param = req.params.parameter;

    articlesCollection.findOne({title:param}, (err,foundArticle) => {

        err ? res.send(err) : res.send(foundArticle);

    })

})

.put(function(req, res){

    articlesCollection.updateOne(
      {title: req.params.parameter},
      {title: req.body.title, content: req.body.content},
      function(err){
        if(!err){
          res.send("Successfully updated the selected article.");
        }
      }
    );
  })

  .patch(function(req,res) {
      articlesCollection.updateOne({title:req.params.parameter}, {$set:{title:req.body.title,
        content: req.body.content}}, function(err){
            if(!err) {
                res.send("successfully updated");
            } else {res.send(err)}
        })
  })

  .delete(function(req,res) {
      articlesCollection.deleteOne({title:req.params.parameter}, function(err){
          err ? res.send(err) : res.send("deleted successfully")
      })
  })

app.listen("3002", function(){
    console.log("Server is running on 3002")
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try console logging the payload received from 'patch' method. Also, You should try mongoose 'findOneAndUpdate' method. It's syntax is similar to:

```
const result = await Model.findOneAndUpdate(
{ _id },
{
title,
content
},
{ new: true }
})
```

Do note that there can be any condition not just _id to match the document you want to update. Mongoose documentation is really detailed as well.

Comment: thank you, but how to console log playload received?

Comment: console log the event and check what do you get in req.body
```

console.log(req. body)
```